# Not able to see a role in Snowflake Webui

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am facing below issue .
I created a role using **ACCOUNTADMIN** role in SnowSQL using below command .

```
CREATE ROLE TASK_USER_ROLE
```

I can see it from SnowSQL Terminal as below

[image]

Similarly , When i query same using Snowflake WebUI i can see it as below.

[image]

But If i try to switch to **TASK_USER_ROLE** , I can't see that role in Snowflake Web UI context.

I tried to switch to ACCOUNTADMIN role in Snowflake UI also .but Still no luck .

Any valid reason for this?? And How can we troubleshoot this ??

Thanks In Advance .

Answer (score 1):

After closely looking at below image , I came to know that even if i created the role ,  have not granted that role to any role . That is the reason **granted_to_roles** field for that role is snowing 0. So i was not able to see same role in WebUI .

[image]

So i ran "GRANT ROLE TASK_USER_ROLE  TO ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;

[image]

[image]

After That i can see this in Web Ui as below

[image]